# Hibernate: avoid Meta Data Locking in MySQL 5.5

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

We have a lot of long running processes in our Spring/Hibernate based application which span one single long running transaction. 
Since we upgraded to MySQL 5.5. we often run into effects of Meta-Data Locking (see https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/02/01/implications-of-metadata-locking-changes-in-mysql-5-5/)

Before MySQL 5.5. we could easily do a ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN even though a long running process was active. This was useful when we do staggered deployments (one server at a time until all servers are deployed with newest code)

With MySQL 5.5. this is not possible anymore, as the long transactions holds a Meta-data lock and we basically need to wait until all long running processes holding those locks have finished. 
In other words: We cannot do DDL statements when there is at least one long running process running.

That basically means a downtime, which we would like to avoid.

Question: Which strategies do exist to handle that situation?

My idea would be:

1. have multiple sessionFactories: 
   a) SessionFactoryA (autocommit=true) for all tables which are not transactional (the ones we would like to touch with DDL statements)
   b) SessionFactoryB (autocommit=false) for all other tables which should be transactional, even during long running processes.

Would that work? Which downsides are there? Any other ideas?